# Error run "app" Target device not found ... Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android

Debugging, connection adb drivers etc are all good but the mobile device not showing in running option.

I have windows 8 installed and android version 3.5 latest installed. In edit configuration there is also no deployment target device option.

Comment: did you put your device in developer mode, allowed usb debugging as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should install adb device interface. It will resolve your problem.

for example official Samsung ADB from here:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

Obviously already you should have below items

enable Developer Mode,

enabled USB debugging,

securely connected USB cable,

In Edit Run/Debug Configurations have "Target: USB Device".